# How do I change the Let's Encrypt CA Endpoint?

Tags: ubuntu, lets-encrypt

Recently, LE did announce that they are making wildcard certs available. Such a great thing! But, whether or not that's active or not, while attempting to test the feature today, I got this error:

> The currently selected ACME CA endpoint does not support issuing wildcard certificates.

This got me wondering, when using `certbot` (am using this on Ubuntu Xenial Xerus), how do I tweak/change the CA endpoint? I hadn't explored this before, but this particular case got me interested.

Comment: Have you upgraded certbot to a version >= `0.22.0`?

Comment: Am looking around `certbot-auto` but see neither "version" flag nor an "update" option. How do you normally proceed concerning its versioning? I know it auto updates, but...

Comment: See what the output of `certbot --version` is, first. I'm not certain, but I suspect if you installed via a package manager you're at the mercy of their update schedule.

Comment: Correct. Though the docs don't mention it, there's a `--version` flag. Okay, am still at 0.22.0. I didn't use a package manager, but let me upgrade all the same. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I've used the package manager now, and got to 0.21.1, but I now get the new error `Wildcard domains are not supported`, meaning the feature hasn't been rolled out yet or?

Comment: `0.21.1` is less than `0.22.0`. It's only supported in `0.22.0` and up. Why did you downgrade?

Comment: I Googled the error message you originally got and found https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5369. Looks like you need a) to go back to `0.22.0` and then use `--server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory` until the next release of certbot.

Comment: Makes sense. At the moment, that seems to be the highest version available for my platform. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, it's based on the verion of certbot that's available for your platform- not all versions support issuance of wildcard domains yet.

https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5369

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `--server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory` to your Certbot command to tell it to use the ACME v2 API that supports Wildcard certificates.

Credits: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certbot-the-currently-selected-acme-ca-endpoint-does-not-support-issuing-wildcard-certificates/55667/2